# Duplicate resources when integrating Firebase crashlytics and Fabric dependencies

Tags: android, duplicates, crashlytics-android

I have the following gradle(:app) file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.twoverte"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0.7"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Room components
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.4'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.2.5"

    //Lifecycle components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0'

    //Kotlin
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.72'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-alpha02'

    //Google
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

    //Networking
    implementation 'com.smartarmenia:dotnetcoresignalrclientjava:1.14'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:5.0.0-preview.2.20167.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'

    //RxJava + RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'

    //Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'

    //Firebase Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //Permissions
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.1.0'

    //UI
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.zhukic:sectioned-recyclerview:1.2.3'
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.2.0"
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:3.0.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550'
    implementation 'com.libRG:customtextview:2.2'

    //Compression
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:3.0.0'

    //Util
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:3.0.0-RC2'
}
```

and the following gralde(:project) file -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        //Firebase Crashlytics
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

For some reason it gives me a `Duplicate resource` error -

[image]

I tried to delete the files that were mentioned there but it did not help as they were re - added and the error appears again and again.

I can't understand where the conflict is, but both libraries seem to not be happy together.

Tried to check for a solution here but nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### FYI

Fabric is <s>deprecated</s> and will be available until **May 4, 2020** for existing users.Crashlytics and Crashlytics Beta have been integrated into Firebase, with new Firebase-only features.

**Don't**

```
 classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0'
 classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
```

**Do**

```
// Add the Fabric Crashlytics plugin.
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
```

In your app-level **`build.gradle`**, add the Crashlytics dependencies:

```
// (Recommended) Add the Google Analytics dependency.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'

// Add the Firebase Crashlytics dependency.
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

Read official guideline about [**`Get started with Firebase Crashlytics`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android).

Answer (score 1):

I maybe wrong, but it seems to me the problem is that you are using fabric and firebase at the same time and fabric is no longer supported as far as I know

"
The Future of Fabric
We have integrated the best of Fabric into Firebase to bring you one powerful app development platform. Fabric is deprecated and will be available until May 4, 2020 for existing users. New users should start in Firebase to take advantage of the latest products and features we're building there. Learn more
"